# Batch file error?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm getting a weird error with one of the codes in my batch file "(1 was unexpected at this time)"

```
@echo off  
md tmp  
echo made tmp folder  
pause  
for %%a (1,2,3) call Do_asst %%a
```

i'm new to batch files but haven't been able to find the problem yet, anyone know why it won
t call the other batch file (Do_asst) and crashes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be:

```
@echo off  
md tmp  
echo made tmp folder  
pause  
for %%a in (1,2,3) do call Do_asst %%a
```

Note the missing "in" and "do"...

Comment: `for %%a in (1,2,3) do call Do_asst %%a` <-- note the added 'do'

Comment: Michael, good catch. I have updated accordingly, but you really deserve half the credit here...